# Expo react-native app suddenly stuck on Splash Screen

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I've been building my expo app for a few months now - has always been working just fine.

I didn't touch it for 2/3 weeks and now, when I run `expo start`, my app gets stuck on the Splash Screen.

I managed to connect to react native debugger and I am getting this error: [image]

> Error: React Refresh runtime should not be included in the production bundle.

> Error: Requiring module "node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/InitializeCore.js", which threw an exception: Error: React Refresh runtime should not be included in the production bundle.

> Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
> This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.

app.json and package.json can be found [here](https://github.com/pelayomartinez/expo-issue/tree/main)

Another thing that might be helpful is that my `App.tsx` code doesn't even get reached (I have a couple of console logs that don't fire).

To anticipate some questions:

- I'm not using `preventAutoHideAsync()`. In fact, I've stripped back the code to just display a single `View` in `App.tsx`
- I haven't changed a single thing (didn't install new packages or change any code). This exact codebase run just fine two weeks ago
- I've tried `yarn cache clean`, deleting node_modules and running `yarn install`, deleting `.expo` and `.expo-shared` folders, and updating to latest expo-cli version
- I've tried running in both a real device and a simulator

Could anyone help diagnose this? Any advice is much appreciated

Comment: Will you please show your package.json and your app.json?

Comment: Hey @server_unknown, thanks for the reply! Here they are: https://github.com/pelayomartinez/expo-issue/tree/main

Comment: Update on this for anyone having the same issue - I tried just moving my project folder to a different location; deleting node_modules and reinstalling; and clearing cache. It now works. Still a mystery - but hopefully this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Just like OP said in a comment, moving my project folder to a different location, deleting `node_modules/`, `ios/` and `android/`  and reinstalling and rebuilding and worked. Not sure why, but moving the project folder seemed to be necessary.